# Apps Script: An unknown error has occurred, please try again later

Tags: google-apps-script

Should this script be causing an error? I haven't done anything with Apps Script in a long time. My Google Sheet doesn't have any sharing restrictions, and I already tried the fix I saw elsewhere in this forum where you add your script to the Library...

```
function onEdit(e){
if(e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A2:A' && 
  e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Your feed'
) 
e.source.getRange('F2:K75').clear()
}
```

Every time I try to run the script, I get the "An unknown error has occurred, please try again later" message.

Thanks!

I tried to create a script to clear a range of cell contents when another cell range was modified.

Comment: Welcome. I've run your script without the "unknown error". Regarding the script itself: 1) I suggest that you include `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` at line 1 - this will show you EXACTLY what Event Objects are available.  2) `e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A2:A'` , the absence of a end Row is unusual when referencing an Event Object. 3)  `e.source.getRange('F2:K75').clear()`: there is a documented method of `getRange` available at spreadsheet level [doc ref}(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation) but the example includes the sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && sh.getName() == 'Your feed') {
    sh.getRange('F2:K75').clear()
  }
}
```